# Loading image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, asp.net-mvc-5

My application is MVC5; I am trying to load an image using JavaScript as follows:

```
<img id="id1" class="img-responsive"/>

    
var img = new Image();
        img.src = "~/Content/images/FILMSTRIP.png";
        img.onload = function() {
            var imageElement = document.getElementById("id1");
            imageElement.src = img.src;
            imageElement.maxWidth = "1592";
            imageElement.maxHeight = "516";
            imageElement.alt = "Activities";
            imageElement.style.marginLeft = "auto";
            imageElement.style.marginRight = "auto";
        };
```

I does not work!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't just access users' file systems using javascript

Comment: you are correct, I used @Url.Content("~/Content/images/FILMSTRIP.png") and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use `@Url.Content("~/Content/images/FILMSTRIP.png")`

Comment: Did you test it on a users machine?